# Read sections from Manual Page using Terminal man command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, gnome-terminal

I would like to read only the sections of what i am looking for in the manual page.

For example to read only the sections of `-k` in the manual page of `man` i can use

```
man man | grep -E '(-k)'
```

The result:

```
man -k [apropos options] regexp ...
man -k printf
-k, --apropos
       which in turn overrides the $PAGER environment variable.  It is not used in conjunction with -f or -k.
```

The result is bad, because is not the all sections i need. 
So currently i am using:

```
man man | grep -E '(-k|'')'
```

The result is all the text, but marked `-k` in red color.

My question is how can i get output similar to this:

```
man -k [apropos options] regexp ...
man -k printf
       Search the short descriptions and manual page names for the keyword printf as regular expression.   Print  out  any  matches.
       Equivalent to apropos printf.
-k, --apropos
          Equivalent to apropos.  Search the short manual page descriptions for keywords and display any  matches.   See  apropos(1)
          for details.
```

Comment: Is it importen for you, to get all lines with -k, including the examples at the overview on beginning of manpage, or is the detail parameter description enough for you?

Comment: Some guy offered `man man | sed '/-k/,/^$/!d'` but it's not working well for `-r`

Comment: Because there are incidental matches of `-r` like `--regex`... you could exclude them by specifying the next char which will be a space or a comma so `man man | sed '/-k[, ]/,/^$/!d'` but obviously stopping at the empty line is not cleanly giving you what you want :S

Comment: The silent addition of the [python] tag doesn't make this a python question. Either rewrite the question so that it has anything to do with python, or remove the tag from the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider what do you mean by the sections of -k (-AnyOther)

For example what about this entry?:

```
   -P pager, --pager=pager
          Specify which output pager to use.  By default, man uses pager -s.  This option overrides the $MANPAGER environment variable, which in turn overrides the $PAGER environment  variable.   It
          is not used in conjunction with -f or -k.
```

It is also related somehow to -k.

Basing on your example I suppose you want to skip this entry.
If so I would recommend using two regular expressions:

```
"^\s*-k" # for the case when -k is at the beginning
"man -k" # self explainable :)
```

From found entries you should print all lines below with more spaces before first printable character than was in your match.

I'm not sure if grep or sed are a proper tools for this job. Personally I would try doing it with python or awk.

Comment: Printing all lines beginning with a line that matches a regular expression and ending with a line that matches another regex is a common job for `awk` and would likely be easier than writing a python script.